# Error con extensión RenderPartialIf en ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-4

Actualmente estoy trabajando con ASP.NET MVC4 C# y en la siguiente linea de código tengo un error en el metodo RenderPartialIf:

```
@{ Html.RenderPartialIf("_Aside", Request.IsAuthenticated); }
```

El metodo RenderPartialIf lo llamo del archivo HtmlHelperExtensions.cs  y el siguiente metodo:

```
public static void RenderPartialIf(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string partialViewName, bool condition)
{
    if (!condition)
        return;

    htmlHelper.RenderPartial(partialViewName);
}
```

Pero en ASP.NET MVC5 C# la linea de codigo funciona correctamente por lo que me gustaría que me ayuden para determinar su equivalencia en ASP.NET MVC4 C# o facilitar algunos manuales o enlaces para llegar a la solución, les agradeceria bastante.

Comment: Que error te muestra?

Comment: No reconoce el método: **RenderPartialIf**.  `Mensaje de error del compilador: CS1061: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' no contiene una definición de 'RenderPartialIf' ni se encontró ningún método de extensión 'RenderPartialIf' que acepte un primer argumento de tipo 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' (¿falta una directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?)`

Comment: Impprtaste el namespace utilizando using?

Comment: He agregado el using System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper pero aun no reconozco el método, tienes algún enlace con la sintaxis para agregar en namespace en using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que agregar el using en la vista para que el compilador pueda encontrar el metodo extension.

Por ejemplo digamos que el namespace y clase donde esta el metodo externo RenderPartialIf es el siguiente:

```
namespace MiAplicacion.Extensiones
{
   public static class HtmlHelperExtensiciones
   {
        public static void RenderPartialIf(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string partialViewName, bool condition){
            if (!condition)
                return;

            htmlHelper.RenderPartial(partialViewName);
        }
   }
}
```

Entonces al inicio de tu vista tienes que hacer lo siguiente:

```
@using MiAplicacion.Extensiones;
```

Y ya podras utilizar el metodo extensor:

```
@Html.RenderPartialIf("", true);
```

Comment: gracias por tu apoyo, solucionado!!!!

Comment: Ya lo habías solucionado?

Comment: Primera vez, gracias a tu apoyo!!!